# How to activate wifi in microsd card?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, sd-card

I created and inserted wpa_suplicant.conf into my raspbian image after `dd`ing it to the micro sd. However, after I plugged it in the raspberry pi, I had to manually click on the wifi icon on the tray and activate it. After it, the wifi connected itself, proving the wpa_supplicant.conf file works.

What should I change in the micro sd card to make wifi turn on in the first boot?

It looks like it waits for me to complete the region and timezone in the welcome window that appears on the first boot. However I already configured the region in wpa_supplicant.conf, so what should I do?

Comment: if you "after dding it to the micro sd" you did something strange. Just try following the recommended procedure https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Revised Answer:

> Flash your SD card using `rpi-imager` instead of using `dd`. Use the "Advanced Options", and select the "Skip first-run wizard" option. That should give you a system that boots as you want - start on first boot with no human intervention.

> `rpi-imager` may be installed in the usual way using the `apt` tools.
> *See below for details*

#### Original Answer:

You should read the [instructions for setup of the wireless LAN in the official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md). There are lots instructions on the Internet (and some here in SE) that have been outdated by changes in RPi OS over the years. If you haven't changed any of the networking config files, the instructions in the official docs should resolve your issue.

If you follow them, and still have problems, please edit your question and explain what you have tried. We'll try to help you get this sorted.

---

Edits to address the OP's comments below:

From the [instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) cited above, here's an alternative to adding the country code with `raspi-config`:

> Alternatively, you can edit the wpa_supplicant.conf file and add the following. (Note: you need to replace 'GB' with the 2 letter ISO code of your country. See Wikipedia for a list of 2 letter ISO 3166-1 country codes.)

> country=GB

If you don't know your country code, [look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1). And don't overlook two other things: ***1)*** Place your `wpa_supplicant.conf` file in the `/boot` directory ([ref](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md)), and ***2)*** **do not** use Windows to create the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file - unless you remove the dreaded *CR-LF* hidden characters from the file before copying it to `/boot`.

---

Another edit (Mar 19, 2021)

[Dmitry has now discovered](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/122271/83790) that `/etc/xdg/autostart/piwiz.desktop` (a.k.a. *first run wizard*) is preventing your RPi Desktop system from automatically booting as the RPi Lite system does. Changes to that code are a [possibility](https://github.com/raspberrypi-ui/piwiz/issues/21), but there may be another way:

The latest version of [Raspberry Pi Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-imager-update-to-v1-6/) has a set of "Advanced Options" that allow you to input the data required by `piwiz.desktop`, and it has an **option to skip the *first run wizard* (aka `piwiz.desktop`)**

And so - if you flash your SD card using `rpi-imager` using the "Advanced Options", **and** select the `Skip first-run wizard`, that should give you a system that boots as you want - start on first boot with no human intervention.

Install `rpi-imager` from the command line in the usual way:

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

*Caveat: as indicated previously, I am unable to verify this on my system, and so I am simply taking the documentation at face value.*

Comment: That's where I learned how to create my own wpa_supplicant. The `raspi-config`, and other commands, however, are for running while booted on raspbian. I want to edit things before running the raspbian, on the sd card

Comment: @LucasZanella: What things specifically? AFAIK, any changes you make in `wpa_supplicant` or `raspi-config` will persist across boots.  Could you explain what you're unable to do?

Comment: I'm making the modifications before the first boot, on my computer, just after I write to the microSD. Raspbian has a prompt screen on the first boot that let you select the region, and based on that, it rewrites my wpa_supplicant file with the selected region. Not only that, it only activates the wifi after I complete this window. I want wifi to work on first boot without any interaction with this window

Comment: @LucasZanella: If that's what you want, then I suggest you read the instructions in the link in my answer. Apparently you need to read them again. Look carefully for the sentence that begins with, `Alternatively, you can edit the wpa_supplicant.conf file and add the following.`

Comment: I did this, this is my wpa_supplicant.conf: `ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=BR
`. However, raspbian refuses to activate the wifi unless I fill the information on the window or click activate wifi on the tray icon, on the first boot

Comment: @LucasZanella: OK... so if you've read the documentation, why did you not read the part where they tell you to use `network={ ...}` ??? Please edit your question to add your `wpa_supplicant.conf` file, *please*. Also add **where** you saved the file (e.g. in `/boot` ??), and finally assure us that you did not create this file on a Windows machine. Alternatively, post your WiFi network's SSID, and a password (not the real one), and we'll create your `wpa_supplicant.conf` for you.

Comment: I did read everything, and I did use `network = {...}`, here's the enitre file: https://pastebin.com/aP1eZmGB and it is on `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`: `pi@raspberrypi:/etc/wpa_supplicant $ cat wpa_supplicant.conf 
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=BR
...`. The file is working, but only after I click on the tray icon and activate the wifi. I did not type any password, simply activating the wifi makes the wifi connect to the password in this file. This is the problem: even if the file is correct I need to activate wifi onfirst boot

Comment: @LucasZanella: All I can tell you is that this works for me.  Is this a "stock" image you copy (`dd`) to the SD card, or something you've created?

Comment: no, it's the raspbian. Perhaps the server version works without user interaction but the desktop version (with additional software) simply won't unless I activate the wifi with mouse on first boot

Comment: That's hard for me to believe, but it may be true - I've seen a couple of other differences between Desktop and Lite that surprised me. But if that's the case - as you say - that Desktop doesn't start the WiFi automatically, I will bet that there is some way to overcome this. Unfortunately, I do not have that answer, and I'll apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: @LucasZanella: I have revised my answer. I feel that the [Raspberry Pi Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-imager-update-to-v1-6/) may be a solution.

Comment: I see no rpi-imager on Ubuntu's repos. And the `.deb` from pi's site is not statically linked so you can't just `dpkg -i` it.

Comment: @vesperto: You should probably submit this as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

All tutorials I have seen which activate WiFi on the first boot use the Lite OS version. Perhaphs that's what is preventing it from activating automatically in your case (I understand you use the GUI). One notable difference is the first boot wizard, which can be deactivated by removing

```
/etc/xdg/autostart/piwiz.desktop
```

or running `sudo apt purge piwiz` (you need to login to the Pi via SSH or chroot into Pi root fs on a system with working `apt`).

Another source of problems is the content of `wpa_supplicant.conf` itself. The recommended file for headless setup looks like this:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=<Insert 2 letter ISO 3166-1 country code here>

network={
 ssid="<Name of your wireless LAN>"
 psk="<Password for your wireless LAN>"
}
```

Make sure you use UNIX line endings.

Comment: My wpa_supplicant.conf is exacly as this one, but it won't work on raspbian full desktop. Maybe some other file must be edited to tell the raspbian first bot wizard that it does not need to be run, and also that wifi can be activated by default

Comment: @LucasZanella Try removing `piwiz.desktop` file.

Comment: That might do the trick! [This guide](https://diyprojects.io/pi-imager-piwiz-desktop-wizard-installation-raspberry-pi-os-raspbian/) claims that `piwiz.desktop` is actually deleted after the first use. The only potential hitch is there are some other things that are set with this (language, keyboard, timezone), so they may need to be set elsewhere. Good find!

Comment: @Seamus `piwiz` can be re-run at a later time, either manually or using a script which checks for certain conditions. Then there's `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` / `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` which should do the same thing. The real question is whether non-wokring WiFi is really the wizard's doing

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev but piwiz is the thing that activates wifi, because wifi only works if I fill piwiz or if I turn it on in the tray. SO removing it will prevent me from filling piwiz

Comment: @LucasZanella: I think the point is this: `piwiz` demands that the user provide information needed to start WiFi. But if that information can be supplied ahead of time (as is done in the Lite RPi distro), then `piwiz` can be eliminated.

Comment: @LucasZanella It's also possible that piwiz desactivates the WiFi when run, and reactivates it at the end, so not running it at all could solve the problem. I don't have time to analyze what it does exactly, but looking at the [source](https://github.com/raspberrypi-ui/piwiz/blob/master/src/piwiz.c) and searching for `vsystem` reveals most of its actions.